# Facing Issue with using System.Web.Routing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web, url-routing

I am using slideshow on my website. Its works fine when i disable the web routing.
When i enable the Web Routing on aspx pages, Slideshow working stops. I guess javascript not working after enabling Web routing.

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
 }

  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
    routes.MapPageRoute("CategoryRoute", "Category/{sCatId}", "~/Category.aspx",true);
    routes.MapPageRoute("SubCategoryRoute", "SubCategory/{catid}",   "~/SubCategory.aspx");
 }
```

Routing works fine when i am using it, but working slideshow stops.
Below i am pasting slideshow code.

```
<div id="slider">
            <div id="items">
                <div>
                    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 0; height: 250px">
                        <img src="http://www.yepme.com/slider/1.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 0; height: 250px">
                        <img src="http://www.yepme.com/slider/2.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 0; height: 250px;">
                        <img src="http://www.yepme.com/slider/3.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 0; height: 250px;">
                        <img src="http://www.yepme.com/slider/4.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
</div>
```

Don't know what the problem is ? how it can be resolved.

I also used

```
<img src= '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("http://www.yepme.com/slider/4.jpg") %>' alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

But it didn't work for me. Guys Help me !

Answer (score 0):

Are your jpeg files delivered through a custom handler ?

If so, did you try adding some specific ignore for your slideshow ? Something like :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

 routes.Ignore("{*sliderimages}", new { sliderimages =@"slider/\d+\.jpg"});

 routes.MapPageRoute("CategoryRoute", "Category/{sCatId}", "~/Category.aspx",true);
 routes.MapPageRoute("SubCategoryRoute", "SubCategory/{catid}",   "~/SubCategory.aspx");
}
```